# CDF of the sum of 2 random variables uniformly distributed

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

I'm trying to understand the solution to a homework problem and am getting nowhere.  The explanation given is really unspecific and I have no idea what the thought process was behind solving this problem.  Any insight into what this solution is supposed to mean would be greatly appreciated!

[image]

Thank you so much!

Comment: Please do [not use pictures for critical portions](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/20529/290189) of your post. Pictures may not be legible, cannot be searched and are not viewable to some, such as those who use screen readers. [Scanned pages from books are discouraged on SE network](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/155600/259305). Questions should contain sufficient context so that it is [answerable with the text alone](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1807/290189).

Comment: Gotcha, thanks for the downvote ;) @GNUSupporter8964民主女神地下教會

Comment: I'll remove my downvote if you correct this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- $F_Z(z)=P(Z \le z) = P(X+Y \le z)$
- Because $(X,Y)$ is uniformly distributed in the triangle $D = \{0 \le y \le x \le 1\}$, for any subset $A$ of the plane, we have $P(X+Y \in A) = \frac{\text{area}(A \cap D)}{\text{area}(D)}$.
- If you can draw a picture of $A = \{(x,y) : x + y \le z\}$, you can use what the solution calls "simple geometry" to compute $\text{area}(A \cap D)$.

Comment: I can't accept for another 7 minutes for some reason, but when I'm allowed to I will accept your answer.  Thank you so much!